# Allow local admins to run application without having to "Run as Administrator"

Tags: c#, windows-7, permissions, admin, uac

I work on a .NET-based project that has certain features that we only want to be available to administrators.  The methods that control access to these features are decorated with the [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx) like so:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role=@"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
public static void RunAdminFeature()
{
    // code here
}
```

Many of our users are local administrators on their systems, and yet, we've found that they still have to right-click the application icon and select the "Run as Administrator" option in order for these features to be available to them.

From the question and answer [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/why-do-i-have-to-run-as-administrator-in-windows-7/3eead260-4974-4219-8c1b-325c3831031c), it would appear that this is the expected behavior on Windows 7.  And if so, then it looks like modifying the application shortcut as described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx) might be the expected solution.  If that's the case, then so be it.

My question is two-fold.

1. Am I doing things right programmatically?  Is the attribute approach the correct one?
2. Is there a programmatic means of achieving restricted access to certain features that would also allow local administrators to run the application without requiring them to explicitly "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: This is a good question and one I have myself asked in various forums (trying to find the links to these now). As far as I can recall (and as you point out) asking users to modify the shortcut was definitely a way around this problem. However, there is another method which depends on which install package you are using? I have not seen the attribute approach used but would be interested to hear of any success you have had. To the second point I would say no, without discussion. Having read into this I have not found a suitable method for doing this. Registering with the UAC all you can do...

Comment: @Killercam, the attribute approach appears to work although we're not restricting access is the right places within the code.  For example, if a local admin runs our app without "Run as Administrator," they can still (unfortunately) access the features from the UI, but the features don't work right in this case.  AFAIK, ordinary users experience this same behavior all the time.  Once local administrators "Run as Administrator," those features works as expected.  As far as installer, we use InstallShield, but I don't think we do anything special related to this issue.

Comment: Modifying the application shortcut is the correct answer.

Comment: @JimMischel I'd disagree, and say self-elevation is a better method, per Sheng Jiang's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 The attribute approach is OK. You just need to handle the security exception correctly (e.g. offer to restart the app as administrator).

2 Hide the admin interface in your app so normal user can use, except you add a "god mode" button somewhere to enable  the admin interface in elevated mode. An example is Windows Task Manager requiring elevation to see processes from all users.

For sample code for self-elevation, visit [How to self-elevate an application to a high privilege level under UAC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981778).